# C# date time format issue need data dd/mm/yy hh:mm

Tags: c#, .net

I want to  display date in this format dd/mm/yy hh:mm

```
HrCreatedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(objMessagePoco.CreatedDate.ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it's giving me an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Why is that?

Comment: You are using `DateTime.ParseExact` to display a date in a format? You use `DateTime.ToString(format)` to display a date in a format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.ParseExact` parses a string into a DateTime. If you just want to format an existing DateTime as a string, just pass the format to `ToString`:

```
var myStr = objMessagePoco.CreatedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
```

Comment: Have a look at DateJS: https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers - might have been worth mentioning this in your question, given that you tagged it C# and .net, posted C# code and made no mention of jQuery.

Comment: Hi, yes ...Questions is about for c# and now wanted to use same date format with jQuery...

Comment: There's nothing out of the box for date formatting - look at DateJS.

Comment: Ant:I can not change year in jquery date picker with Bootstrap modal.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949242/jquery-ui-calendar-year-and-months-dropdown-selection-with-choosing-different-ye

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue was you needed uppercase MM for month.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: You are right. Read too quick, plus didn't put enough thought into answer.-1 for me. Sorry.